Why am I not getting faster computations when I increase my EC2 vCPUs?
I have to run a code on MATLAB that I can't optimize so I have to increase my computational power. The code already uses parallel processing.
I have installed MATLAB both on Ubuntu and Windows on AWS and I'm testing at the same time on my Mac. No matter how much I increase the number of vCPUs on AWS, I'm not getting a meaningful change in the performance (i.e. code execution time). There is a difference between 2 vCPUs and 36, but there's not much difference between the EC2s and my Mac with an Apple M2 chip (probably 8 cores).
So my question is

Why am I not getting a higher performance from that many cores on AWS?
How do I estimate the computational power I need to reduce computation time?

I tried on a Mac with 16 cores and the computation time was reduced but it's not enough information for me to calculate the specifications of the device/server I'm going to need.
On AWS I have tried c4.8xlarge (Ubuntu) and c6a.48xlarge (Windows). For Ubuntu I run MATLAB from the terminal with no display.
I am working with the HCTSA toolbox and I'm timing based on a sample dataset they have provided in the tutorials that can be accessed here
TS_Init('INP_Bonn_EEG.mat');         %%% prepares the input for the main function
TS_Compute(true, 1:10);


You have given us zero context about what code you're trying to run or how it's parallelised, which makes this practically impossible to answer...

I'm running the HCTSA toolbox [link] (https://github.com/benfulcher/hctsa) and I don't exactly know how it's parallelized except that it uses parpool. It's supposed to calculate ~7000 time series features but I thought my question about the vCPUs was more general because I don't think it's specific just to this toolbox, they seem to have a poor performance with Matlab at least.

It would be far easier to suggest improvements to your code if your question contained a [mcve]. It looks like there's a bare call to parpool  in that repo, which starts a pool on the local machine with one worker per physical CPU core up to the limit set in the default profile. Maybe you've hit that limit, have you checked you're utilising all the cores you have available?

Check how many workers are started by MATLAB by printing the NumWorkers field of the object returned by the parpool call. Does this number match your expectation?

Likely though the algorithm is implemented in a way that benefits from a few workers but not from many workers. We need to see a [mre] to know. Finally, the shared memory parallelism of the threads-based parallel pool, if the code works there, will be much more efficient in general.

yes I tampered with the default number of workers from 48 to 300 on an instance with 96 cores and 192 CPUs. the time changed from 3 mins to 2.7 for the sample dataset I am working on. I'm only running this on a portion of a sample dataframe atm. The code is: TS_Init('INP_Bonn_EEG.mat'); TS_Compute(true, 1:10);
The dataset can be accessed here: link

That is not the code, those are not standard MATLAB functions. Please provide a [mre], something we can run without having to download 3rd party stuff that will change or disappear over time. Stack Overflow is a repository of questions and answers, the goal is for these questions to remain valid and meaningful over time. That means they must be self-contained. You’re only interested in getting help, but we’re only interested in building this Q&A database for the future. If you want our help you need to help us too. :)


Q1 :" Why am I not getting a higher performance from that many cores on AWS? "

Because any and all changes in processing performance ( be it increased or decreased ) was principally explained to be dependent on :
(a) yes - increased resources ( added vCPU(s), well way better in a non-shared form of real, process dedicated CPUs )
(b) but also added ( not present so far ) overheads ( be it a new work to be done to "deliver" some part of the work to "new" resources - SER / DES for IPC for example - and the same on the way "back", to collect results from "remote" resources; next add-on overhead kind is degradation of efficiency of cache-hits/miss statistics, decreasing speed to retrieve data from storage ( data in cache gets faster evicted by "other" cores, not working before (a), that put "their" pieces in data into shared cache, so your "first" CPU-core has to re-fetch the once pre-fetched piece of data again from RAM (paying 10x ~ 100x more time, than to get it from (now evicted) cache on-core/on-CPU storage location )

Q2 :" How do I estimate the computational power I need to reduce computation time? "

Quantitatively exact formulation is in revised Amdahl's Law. You will get exact effect of adding more resources on resulting computing time - details are here and applications ( even with interactive graphical simulator of Amdahl's argument ) are here.
Interactive simulator is linked to this picture - so feel free to use it with a click-through :

